# Why is "The [integer<->float] conversion strategy is changed depending on the size of the float" in Erlang and how can I observe this?

Tags: floating-point, erlang

The [Erlang docs](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html) say:

"When comparing an integer to a float, the term with the lesser precision is converted into the type of the other term, unless the operator is one of =:= or =/=. A float is more precise than an integer until all significant figures of the float are to the left of the decimal point. This happens when the float is larger/smaller than +/-9007199254740992.0. The conversion strategy is changed depending on the size of the float because otherwise comparison of large floats and integers would lose their transitivity."

### How is this change in conversion strategy for large floats observable?

I read the docs as saying that `(...digits).0 == (...digits)` would be false for a small sequence of `(...digits)` but true for a larger sequence (...digits) but that doesn't seem to be the case for the value they gave:

```
> 9007199254740992.0 == 9007199254740992
true
> 9.0 == 9.
true
```

However, it does seem to be the case for larger numbers. Are the docs out of date with regard to the specific boundary at which the conversion strategy changes?

```
> 999999999999999999999.0 ==  999999999999999999999.
false
> 9.0 == 9.
```

true

### Why?

The reason given for the change in strategy of float<->integer comparison for larger numbers is "otherwise comparison of large floats and integers would lose their transitivity." I don't follow–is there an example of how this algorithm avoids transitivity failure?

Comment: For your second example, note that `999999999999999999999.0` cannot be accurately represented as a float. The return value of `trunc(999999999999999999999.0)` is `1000000000000000000000`, and thus `999999999999999999999.0 == 1000000000000000000000` returns `true`.

Comment: "A float is more precise than an integer" No, at best it may have the same precision. of course an integer is an integer, it is absolutely not suitable for rational or real numbers. There very few cases where a float is absolutely precise, it is something that must be considered when comparing them together, or to integers (see IEEE representation of float)

Comment: @Pascal, the thing you said "no" to is a fraction of a sentence I quoted from the docs (link above). The full sentence is "A float is more precise than an integer until all significant figures of the float are to the left of the decimal point" . 

Another sentence from the quote: "The conversion strategy is changed depending on the size of the float". My question is 'Why is “The [integer<->float] conversion strategy is changed depending on the size of the float” in Erlang and how can I observe this?'

Comment: @Max, I know, what I really wanted to say is that it is a bad idea to mix float and integer. To be clear something like: Qty = 3, UnitWeight = 1.5, TotalWeight = Qty*UnitWeight makes sense (if QTY is always an integer). But MyWeightToday = 80, MyWeightYesterday = 79.6 should not be used. Integer and float are using two different representations for different purposes, the first having an absolute precision of 1, the second having a relative precision in a (almost) constant range. This said, the libraries do their best to avoid discrepancy when mixing the 2 types (see legoscia answer)

Comment: Thanks @Pascal, I completely agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider these three numbers:

```
A = 9007199254740992.
B = 9007199254740993.
C = 9007199254740992.0.
```

Under the actual rules, `A` and `C` are equal to each other and different from `B`:

```
> A == B.  %% A and B are both integers, compared as integers
false
> A == C.  %% C gets converted to an integer before comparison
true
> B == C.  %% C gets converted to an integer before comparison
false
```

What if it were the other way around, so that integers above the threshold were converted to floats before comparison to floats?

```
> A == B.         %% no change, because they are both integers
false
> float(A) == C.  %% no surprise here
true
> float(B) == C.  %% B cannot be accurately represented as a floating point value!
true
```

So now it looks like `A` and `B` are both equal to `C`, but not equal to each other, and the equality comparison has lost its transitivity.

9007199254740992 is equal to 2<sup>53</sup>, and 53 is also the number of significand bits in a 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point number<sup>*</sup>, so for numbers greater than this the floating point type is not able to represent every integer.  For example, `9007199254740992.0 + 1 == 9007199254740992.0` returns `true`.  That is why the Erlang integer type (which is a bignum, and can thus represent arbitrarily large integers) is considered more precise above this threshold.

<sup>* The binary representation uses only 52 bits for the significand, and gets away with this because the first bit is almost always 1. Search for "subnormal numbers" to learn more.</sup>

Comment: Thanks @legoscia. What is the significance of the threshold? Your first example seems like what I was looking for, but it works even if B is `5`. Is there a way that I can observe that the threshold is relevant?

Comment: The significance of the threshold is that it is the lowest number where `C == C + 1` is `true`. That is, the floating point type doesn't hold enough accuracy to represent every single integer past this point.

Comment: For anyone reading these comments:  `9007199254740992.0 =:= 9007199254740992.0 + 1` indeed evaluates to `true`.

Comment: In `A == C` the int gets promoted to a float, not the other way around. https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#term-comparisons

Answer (score 1):

Given that floats and integers have different precissions (floats have higher resolution with values closer to 0 and lower resolution with values further away from 0), if you want to compare them you need to transform one of them to the other.

If this transformation is from the one with higher precission to the one of lower precission, this would be possible:

```
H2 = H1 + Delta,
true = L == H1,
true = L == H2,
true = H1 /= H2. %% In this case, both H1 and H2 are equal to L but different between themselves
```

For this reason (transitivity), the transformation is performed the other way around, from lower precssion to higher precission.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why is “The [integer<->float] conversion strategy is changed depending on the size of the float” in Erlang and how can I observe this?

Comment: @MaxHeiber 
`true =  0.0000000001 > 0.`, `true =  0.0000000001 < 1.`: Floats have increased resolution when close to 0.
`true = 9999999999999999999999999999.0 < 9999999999999999999999999999.` Floats lose resolution with large values.
You have it explained more in depth in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Do you know what the significance of the numbers from the docs are? +/-9007199254740992.0 -- I couldn't see anything special happening around this value. Thanks for your help

Comment: @MaxHeiber 9007199254740992 is 2**53, which is the size of the base for double-precission floating point numbers. Once you have an integer that's greater than 9007199254740992, it will have more precission than the same number represented as a float: `true = 9007199254740993.0 < 9007199254740993.` `false = 9007199254740992.0 < 9007199254740992.`